# Reload a class with different parameters

Tags: java, swing, exit, systemexit

So I have a code which is like:

**Class A**

**Class B**

```
methodB(frame initialization)
```

**Class C**

```
methodC(frame initialization)
```

An object of **ClassA** calls *ClassB* and then a frame is initialized. Now when a button on *ClassB* is pressed an object of  *ClassC* is initialized.

When a button on *ClassC* is pressed I need to reinitialize an object of *ClassA* with updated parameters. So while  reinitializing an object of *ClassA* from *ClassC*, the older object of *ClassC* is still there.

**How do I exit from the old object of *ClassA* and initialize a new object of *ClassA* when a particular button is pressed?** I am able to create a new instance of *ClassA* but the problem is in exiting from the previous object from *ClassC* because if I add `System.exit(0)` in *classC*, it closes both objects of *ClassA*. I just want the old object to close.

Comment: If you use singleton, you will only have 1 instance of A. So, if you initialize it twice, the first instance will be replaced by the second one.

Comment: Use class constructor...

Comment: @AliBZ : Singleton is a great option.

Comment: @StanislavMamontov : Can you elaborate ??

Comment: Your question does not make any sense, you should first become clear what a class is, what an object is and what a method is. You dont call a "Class", you call a method of an object (which is an instance of some class). And you dont initialize a class (but possibly you instantiate/initialze an object instance).

Comment: @GyroGearless : Thanx, I have tried to update.

Comment: @MAD_ABOUT_JAVA you created too much frames on runtime, see CardLayout, then every hockey described in your question will be/are/ could be Background or Workers threads, your descriptions is not clear, mentioned .....

Comment: `System.exit()` terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. So basically, your entire program shuts down. That's why it closes both objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: You can't do this. You can't reinitialize `this` or overwrite an instance globally by reconstructing it.

You need to keep a reference to the existing class A instance. When creating an instance of class B, make it accept class A in the constructor and pass `this`. The same when creating class C. Now if you have proper getters, you can, in C, call `this.getB().getA().performSomeUpdate()` whre `performSomeUpdate` updates the A instance to new parameters by setting fields.

Comment: I am doing this thing only . The problem I am facing is that there is a GUI initialized in B with previous parameters. The parameters are updated but they would be used only after restart .

Comment: Remember, this is also dependent upon what types of objects ClassA, ClassB, and ClassC are. If they are some kind of internal frame (for instance), you can hide them and make them visible; each action producing a GUI event that your code could listen to and do stuff when these events take place. In essence, you could "reinitialize" your internal frames via the listeners. Of course, this is just one example.